# xdebug not breaking in controller at all using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug

I am trying to use xdebug with visual studio code.

but nothing is working out.
Installed and enabled xdebug and I am a visual Studio code extension PHP debug.
Please review my setting below and guide me if I am doing something wrong.

php.ini settings

```
[xDebug]
zend_extension="C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.0.24-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=Yes
;xdebug.client_port=80
;xdebug.remote_port=80
xdebug.log="C:\laragon\debug.log"
xdebug.log_level=7
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.client_host="mysite.test"
```

launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 80,
        "pathMappings": {
            "C:/laragon/www/adamjee": "${workspaceFolder}",
        },
        "ignore": [
            "**/vendor/**/*.php"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 0,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
        ],
        "env": {
            "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
            "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
            "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
            "-S",
            "localhost:0"
        ],
        "program": "",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 9003,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
            "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
            "action": "openExternally"
        }
    }
]
```

}

please guide where I am doing wrong.

xdebug logs

```
    [14160] Log opened at 2023-07-27 12:26:08.027714
[14160] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: adamjee.test:80.
[14160] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: adamjee.test:80 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[14160] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/laragon/www/adamjee/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.24" protocol_version="1.0" appid="14160" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.2.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2023 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[14160] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[13228] Log opened at 2023-07-27 12:26:09.225547
[13228] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: adamjee.test:80.
[14160] Log closed at 2023-07-27 12:26:09.226357

[13228] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: adamjee.test:80 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[13228] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/laragon/www/adamjee/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.24" protocol_version="1.0" appid="13228" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.2.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2023 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[13228] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[13228] Log closed at 2023-07-27 12:26:13.534187

[13228] Log opened at 2023-07-27 12:26:13.661112
[13228] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: adamjee.test:80.
[13228] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: adamjee.test:80 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[13228] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/laragon/www/adamjee/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.24" protocol_version="1.0" appid="13228" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.2.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2023 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[13228] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[13228] Log closed at 2023-07-27 12:26:15.526825

[13228] Log opened at 2023-07-27 12:26:15.544789
[13228] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: adamjee.test:80.
[13228] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: adamjee.test:80 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[13228] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/laragon/www/adamjee/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.24" protocol_version="1.0" appid="13228" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.2.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2023 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[13228] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[13228] Log closed at 2023-07-27 12:26:16.975555
```

Comment: `xDeubg` is that a typo in the question or in your php.ini file?

Comment: @apokryfos not at all.

Comment: super personal recommendation, get PHPStorm EAP (so it is free) and use a real IDE for PHP. Some coworkers had so many issues trying to use VSCode with PHP, that was just a massive pain... PHPStorm, 0 issues...

Comment: @matiaslauriti already using PHPStorm :)

Answer (score 1):

The following bits in your `php.ini` configuration:

```
;xdebug.client_port=80
;xdebug.remote_port=80
```

and in your `launch.json`:

```
"port": 80,`
```

Are both wrong. Remove them.

---

Xdebug needs to connect to a port that your IDE is listening on. This is by default 9003, which is also what VS Code has as default. Please remove this line from your configuration.

Right now, you're instructing Xdebug to connect to port 80 (which your logs indicate that it is doing):

```
[13228] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: adamjee.test:80 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[13228] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/laragon/www/adamjee/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.24" protocol_version="1.0" appid="13228" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.2.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2023 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
```

But that is your *web server* listening there, and your web server doesn't understand the Xdebug protocol, and hence then closes the connection after two seconds of being confused:

```
[13228] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
[13228] Log closed at 2023-07-27 12:26:15.526825
```